# Mongoid history_track gem not tracking changes when embedded documents change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, versioning

I've got the following three models:

```
class ItemGroup
    include Mongoid::Document

    embeds_many :item_attributes

    field :name
end

class ItemAttribute
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::History::Trackable

    embedded_in :item_group

    track_history :track_create => true

    field :name
    field :min
    field :max
    field :type

    embeds_many :item_attribute_values
end

class ItemAttributeValue
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::History::Trackable

    embedded_in :item_attribute

    track_history :on => [:name, :order], :track_create => true, :scope => :item_group_attribute, :track_delete => true

    field :name
    field :order
end
```

An example of how this would be used:

```
item_group: {
  name: "Televisions",
  item_attributes: [
    { name: "Screen Size", min: 14, max: 90 type: "single" },
    { name: "Screen Type", min:0, max: 0, type: "multiple", item_attribute_values: [
        { name: "LCD", order: 0 },
        { name: "LED", order: 1 },
        { name: "Plasma", order: 2 }
     ]}
  ]
}
```

What I really care about for version history is the ItemAttributes. Right now, if something is changed in an ItemAttribute ( ex: name, min, max, or type ), a new version will be created. However, if an ItemAttributeValue is updated, deleted, or added it won't create a new ItemAttribute -- which is what we want. For example, if someone adds the ItemAttributeValue { name: 'CRT', order: 3 } to "Screen Types", then the "Screen Types" ItemAttribute should get a new version. Version 1 would have "LCD","LED","Plasma", Version 2 would have "LCD","LED","Plasma","CRT". And if someone removed an ItemAttributeValue, that would create yet another version.

Previously, ItemAttribute wasn't embedded in ItemGroup, so I was able to use Mongoid::Versioning and that worked exactly as I wanted it to. However, the decision was made to embed ItemAttribute within ItemGroup, and I wasn't able to use Mongoid::Versioning anymore, so I switched to Mongoid::History::Tracks. This works fine for tracking changes within the model, but it isn't tracking when a models embedded documents are updated.

I'm starting to think that I'm going to have to fork mongoid_history to add the ability to have an option or something that tells the gem to track updates to a models embedded documents.

Anybody run into a situation like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a gem that solved my problem, mongoid-delorean.